# Get JSON version of a google image search page

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I was watching [this tutorial on using `AFNetworking` in iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QUfd5bRXNk), and the guy instructed us to use a link to a twitter page that was displayed in JSON format. Now, I'm wondering how easy it is to get JSON from a given web page. Say, for example, [this google image search for "beautiful fish"](https://www.google.com/search?q=fish&es_sm=91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=rwmaU-HTFYulyASjoYHACg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ#q=beautiful+fish&tbm=isch).

I want to get all the images from this page using the `AFNetworking` framework, which would be a lot easier if I could have a JSON version of the page, but how do I get that?

After following the answer below, it appears that any image search can have its results displayed in JSON format, using this format:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=YOUR%20SEARCH
```

Example:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=beautiful%20fish

More info here:

https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

You'll get results in JSON if you use that APi